# Python possible to update a url link based on user text input?

Tags: python, api, url, gps

Evening :)

I would like to know if it's possible to transfer user input into a url link for use on the Google Static GPS API. Below I've placed a step by step example of what I would like to happen upon the user inputing text:

Original Link: http://www.google.com/search?q=

User Input in Text Field: Brooklyn Bridge, New York
User clicks button to submit text in text field

Final Link:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Thanks a lot,

Lottie

Comment: Hard-coding into a URL like this doesn't sound much like a developer API. You could use the string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) approach as a crude starting point to do this, or look at using the actual Google API tools e.g. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Comment: You could use [urllib.parse.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) in Python 3 or [urllib.urlencode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) in Python 2

Comment: Thank you - urllib.urlencode is useful :) Appreciate it